# Find the dimensions of the window of a spaceship from the perspective of the person in the spaceship

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

A  certain  spaceship  has  a  rectangular  window  that  is  3  meters  wide  and 2  meters  high  when  the ship is at rest on  Earth.  If  the ship departs Earth and travels at a  velocity  of  V=  0.8 c,  calculate  the dimensions  of the  window  a  person on the  spaceship  will  measure.
What is the right answer to this question?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, first time asking here, didn't know. Ill delete it then. Next time I'll follow the policies here when asking such questions.

Answer (score 4):

The relative velocity is zero. So the answer is still 3 meters wide and 2 meters high.